# Wordpress - CSS Remove bottom-border navbar

Tags: css, wordpress, border

I just added a button to my navbar menu in Wordpress called "Test": http://honigwerk.com/test/

I created a class called .btn to personalize its properties:

```
.btn {
    box-shadow: none;
    background: #fee54b;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fee54b, #fdc509);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fee54b, #fdc509);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fee54b, #fdc509);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fee54b, #fdc509);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fee54b, #fdc509);
    border-radius: 8px;
    color: #b77d02;
    border-bottom: none;
}

.btn:hover {
    box-shadow: none;
    background: #fcd63c;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

I want to remove the border under the element when hover, but I can't. It looks like it ignores the **border-bottom:none;** statement...

Could you help me here?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this in your css:

```
.btn a { border-bottom: none !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because it is on the link itself (a). So if you use:

```
.btn:hover > a{
    border-bottom: none !important;
}
```

It should work.

Comment: @gmoraleda i tried this on your site, and it's working. So try it out ;)

Answer (score 0):

try this with important property :

```
.btn > a:hover {
    border: 0 none !important;
}
```